# In Moose, how do I require one of multiple attributes?

Tags: perl, moose

I would like to be able to declare one of a set of mutually dependent attributes required.

Let's assume a simple example of Number 'nr_two' being 'nr_one' + 1, and 'nr_one' being 'nr_two' -1, with one of either having to be passed in upon initialization.

So far, I have seen this problem solved for example through BUILDARGS checks and a lazy builder on each:

```
has 'nr_one' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Num',
    lazy => 1,
    builder => '_build_nr_one',
);
sub _build_nr_one { shift->nr_two - 1; }

has 'nr_two' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Num',
    lazy => 1,
    builder => '_build_nr_two',
);
sub _build_nr_two { shift->nr_one + 1; }

around 'BUILDARGS' => sub {
    my $orig = shift; 
    my $self = shift; 
    my $args = is_hashref($_[0])? $_[0] : { @_ }; 
    die "Either nr_one or nr_two is required!" unless defined $args{nr_one} || defined $args{nr_two};
    return $self->$orig($args);
};
```

Or, avoiding the around:

```
has 'nr_one' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Num',
    predicate => 'has_nr_one',
    lazy => 1,
    builder => '_build_nr_one',
);
sub _build_nr_one { shift->nr_two - 1; }

has 'nr_two' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Num',
    predicate => 'has_nr_two',
    lazy => 1,
    builder => '_build_nr_two',
);
sub _build_nr_two { shift->nr_one + 1; }

sub BUILD { 
    my $self = shift;
    die "Either nr_one or nr_two is required!" unless $self->has_nr_one || $self->has_nr_two;
}
```

However, I am looking for something that can be declared on the attributes,
for example a grouping of some sort that can then be introspected and, for example, triggered in BUILD.

Ideally, I'd like to ship this into a generic role or Meta class to make it available
with some sort of nicer syntax, to avoid having to check for BUILD(ARGS) checks
or rely on the pod to declare things accurately.

Is there cpan module that could help with this, or a pattern someone is aware of to achieve this?
Any hints / partial solutions are appreciated, if not :)

An example of what I would imagine would look something like this:

```
has 'nr_one' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Num',
    lazy => 1,
    builder => '_build_nr_one',
    required_grouping => 'NumberGroup',
);
sub _build_nr_one { shift->nr_two - 1; }

has 'nr_two' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Num',
    lazy => 1,
    builder => '_build_nr_two',
    required_grouping => 'NumberGroup',

);
sub _build_nr_two { shift->nr_one + 1; }

# when initialized without any attributes, error thrown:
# "One of 'nr_one', 'nr_two' is required"
# or, probably easier: "NumberGroup required!"
```

Comment: Please give an example of how the grouping is supposed to work

Comment: Done, @HåkonHægland . I'm happy for other suggestions that fill my need, though, don't feel constrained by the example.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a way to make a custom [`MooseX::Type`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Types) or [attribute trait](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Attributes#Attribute-traits-and-metaclasses) automatically add a method modifier to [`BUILDARGS()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Construction#BUILDARGS) that would validate the attributes. But it is simple to do that with a [`Moose::Role`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Role) like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
package NumberGroup;
use Moose::Role;
around 'BUILDARGS' => sub {
    my $orig = shift; 
    my $self = shift; 
    my $args = (ref $_[0]) eq "HASH" ? $_[0] : { @_ }; 
    die "Either nr_one or nr_two is required!" unless defined $args->{nr_one} || defined $args->{nr_two};
    return $self->$orig($args);
};


package Main;
use Moose;

with 'NumberGroup';

has 'nr_one' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    isa      => 'Num',
);

has 'nr_two' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    isa      => 'Num',
);

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;
Main->new();
```

**Output**:

```
Either nr_one or nr_two is required! at ./p.pl line 8.
```

Comment: That ships the same logic into a role - which may or may not be considered an improvement ( action at a distance ), but, either way, can't be introspected. The background is I'm trying to validate data  passed into an object, which requires introspection of the attributes.

I could leave this to Moose, but Moose's error handling is not all that I would like to have. Anyhow, using a parameterized role, I could at least use this as a blueprint to make the approach more uniform.

Comment: What do you mean by "introspection"? Why cannot  `BUILDARGS()` in the role can do the introspection?

Comment: I mean that the normal `required` can be introspected using Moose::Meta::Attribute.
This cannot, as it's not in the attribute meta information. It's not really declared as far as Moose is concerned

Comment: It is still not still not clear to me why you need introspection in addition to the role as I suggested in my answer. What extra benefits would you get from the introspection?

Comment: You could make this dynamic by tagging your attributes with a custom trait, and then have the `around BUILDARGS` take care of it automatically. You could then release this as a MooseX thing.

Comment: Thank you @simbabque - I will give that a try and post the result, hopefully tomorrow. Packaging it up will take a bit of time though, as I'm not familiar with that process.

Comment: @bytepusher there are a few useful tools for that. You can look into Dist::Zilla or one of the smaller tools like https://metacpan.org/pod/Minilla. That one is nice to start out, and will include everything from a dist scaffold to releasing to CPAN once you've made an account. If you want help with releasing, get the code on CPAN and I'm happy to jump in and set up the release for you.

Comment: Ah thanks for the hints, that's much appreciated, and I may take you up on your offer. I have managed to do a simple first iteration with some basic tests, but I'm currently stuck into work, there's a release, etc.
I will get back to you on the weekend :)